# Can't initialize a google map in shieldSplitter after doing a splitter.refresh

Tags: javascript, google-maps, shieldui

I have a google map that works fine in a pane.  but if I dynamically change the settings for the splitter with this first:

```
var splitter = jQuery("#container").swidget(),
options = splitter.initialOptions;
options.panes = [ { size: '65%', min: '250px' }, { size: '35%' } ];
options.orientation = 'horizontal';
splitter.refresh(options);
funcShowTheMap();
```

My function funcShowTheMap() to init and show may map, which does work fine, will not show the map anymore.  But simply commenting out the splitter.refresh(options) line will show the map fine in the pane.

Anyone know how to get it to simply (re)show a map after a splitter.refresh???  I've tried the google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') but it does nothing. Its specifically a sheildSpliter problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the Google Map initialization code right after the `.shieldSplitter()` initialization code?